# Google Map is not working properly in my website

Tags: php, google-maps, google-api

i developed a Booking form in my website, and there i put the From and To address and click on the Next, at the next page i get the From address and To address, and pass that to the google map where i calculate the Distance between these two address, everything is working fine, but if i enter the From address "Orlando International Airport, Orlando, FL, United States" and the to address "Disney Springs, Orlando, FL, United States " then its not calculate the Distance, can anyone help me regarding that issue ?

Below are the link for the Booking form:
http://www.vipexpresslimo.net/taxi-from-orlando-airport/

Comment: Please come up with a better title, the current title "Google Map not working properly," is way too broad.

Comment: Bro can you please check the issue and help me :(

Comment: The title still says nothing about the actual problem.  An [mvce] should be provided **in the question itself** not (only) a link to a broken external site.

Comment: The geocoder doesn't know about "Disney Springs, Orlando, FL, United States"

Answer (score 1):

I understand you are using text values from your autocomplete elements.

I would suggest using a Place ID instead of text value. When user selects an address you can grab a Place ID and pass it to directions service.

Please have a look at this sample:

http://jsbin.com/xuyisem/1/edit?html,output

If I put in autocomplete addresses from your question and use place IDs I can see a route.

Hope it helps!